# Cannot run the query for my login form

Tags: php, mysql

even though the account is created in the table, I cannot log in with it, I get the 'Wrong Username or Password' error message after entering the newly made account. Trying to run the query, it will just end at `if($count !== 1) echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Wrong Username or Password</div>';`, anything that I'm doing wrong here? maybe it has to do with something from the database,  Please advise.

[image regarding issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A70H3.jpg)

login.php file

```
session_start();

include("connection.php");

$missingEmail = '<p><stong>Please enter your email address!</strong></p>';
$missingPassword = '<p><stong>Please enter your password!</strong></p>'; 

if(empty($_POST["loginemail"])){
  $errors .= $missingEmail;   
    }else{
   $email = filter_var($_POST["loginemail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
}
if(empty($_POST["loginpassword"])){
  $errors .= $missingPassword;   
}else{
$password = filter_var($_POST["loginpassword"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}

if($errors){

$resultMessage = '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $errors .'</div>';
echo $resultMessage;   
}else{

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $password);
$password = hash('sha256', $password);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password' AND activation='activated'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if(!$result){
echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error running the query!</div>';
exit;
}
   $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
//If email & password don't match print error
if($count !== 1){
echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Wrong Username or Password</div>';
}
else {
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
$_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
$_SESSION['email']=$row['email'];

}
}
}
```

index.js file

```
$("#loginform").submit(function(event){ 
//prevent default php processing
event.preventDefault();
//collect user inputs
var datatopost = $(this).serializeArray();
console.log(datatopost);

$.ajax({
    url: "login.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: datatopost,
    success: function(data){
        if(data == "success"){
            window.location = "mainpageloggedin.php";
        }else{
            $('#loginmessage').html(data);   
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        $("#loginmessage").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>There was an error with the Ajax Call. Please try again later.</div>");

    }

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you have `$errors .= $missingPassword;` since `$errors` variable has not been created yet, it will cause an error as you already try to concatenate it on the error checker.

You can fix that part by assigning the error variable with a null value first.

```
$errors = '';
if(empty($_POST["loginemail"])){
  $errors .= $missingEmail;   
} else {
  $email = filter_var($_POST["loginemail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
}
if(empty($_POST["loginpassword"])) {
  $errors .= $missingPassword;   
} else {
  $password = filter_var($_POST["loginpassword"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}
```